# USB connect/disconnect repeatedly in Sony Vaio laptop

Tags: usb, sony-vaio

When I connect my phone to any USB port of my Sony Vaio laptop for any purpose (e.g., charging or data transfer), it connects and disconnects repeatedly.  The same thing happens with my iPhone, Nokia Lumia, and another phone.

The problem does not happen with other USB devices, such as a pendrive or Bluetooth dongle.  The problem connecting phones is not affected by whether the laptop is running on battery or AC power.

I read many articles on the Internet but have found no solution.

Comment: Are you connecting just to charge the battery or for another purpose, like data transfer?

Comment: for both purpose

Comment: Do the USB ports on the laptop work properly with other devices?  They're USB 2.0?  Does it make a difference whether the laptop is running on battery or the AC adapter?

Comment: yes i try another phones also same issue and I m using any pendrive bluetooth dongel woking fine just mobile have issue i try 3 phone with diffrent datacables same issue

Comment: So pendrives and bluetooth dongles work but phones don't?  Does it make a difference with the phones whether you are running on battery or AC power?

Comment: no matter i using anything same issue

Comment: if you have skype or gtalk or hangout add me mr.kamalsaroya for easy chat

Comment: If power is not an issue it sounds like a issue to do with mounting. Try going into usb options on your phone and change the setting from eg. Media Transfer Mode(MTP) to Mass Storage Mode(MSC)

Comment: No its not issue in mobile i did everything but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the USB cable. I had tried many cables bought from a local shop but none of them worked.
When bought a cable from Sony VAIO Care it worked.